# SSIS Excel to SQL Server - Long Data on Column Failure

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have an SSIS package set up to use a ForEach File loop.  This loop should pick up all *.xlsx files and transfer them to the SQL Server.

The trouble I am having is with a few of the columns where there may anything from no text to a thousand characters.  When I set up the package using a sample file, and I fill in all those columns with over 255 characters, I can successfully set the columns to DT_NTEXT and transfer the data to the server.

However, once I use REAL files where there are blanks, or anything under 255 characters, it throws an error in SSMS saying "Failed to retrieve long data for column "x."

How am I supposed to get the package to NOT look at the data type on import but just import per the package specs?  I know I seen somewhere that SSMS still looks at the first 8 rows?  So I went ahead and changed "TypeGuessRows" to 0 everywhere it exists.  I did not restart the server, but I did restart SSMS and still have issues.  I also have Delay Validation and ValidateExternalMetaData set to false.

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue?

Update:  Here is a screenshot of the error AFTER applying **BLOBTempStoragePath** and **BufferTempStoragePath**.
[SSIS Long Data Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpEHZ.jpg)

Comment: Have you set the `BLOBTempStoragePath` property of the Data Flow task to a fast drive which the SSIS service has access to? REF: [Set BLOBTempStoragePath and BufferTempStoragePath to Fast Drives](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlperf/2007/05/01/set-blobtempstoragepath-and-buffertempstoragepath-to-fast-drives/)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes; I did apply both of those, deployed, and still got the same error.  I have updated my question to include the errors.

Comment: Do you have any opportunity to pre-convert to a text file? The XLS is basically unusable.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid That was going to be my next step.  The source is an automated server report that creates an .xls file - Due to some other issues I have to convert it to an .xlsx file.  I'm was thinking a .csv file would work, but because there are comment fields I can't use ","  So maybe TAB delimited?  It would be nice if Excel files worked correctly so I didn't have to manipulate.  I don't understand why SSIS thinks it needs to re-evaluate the datatype.

Comment: It's not SSIS that's the problem, it's the excel driver. SSIS just does what it's told. Excel is a bad data interchange format. So is CSV (a comma delimited text file). Tab delimited is much better.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I was able to use was to use Excel Macros to convert, or SaveAs, as tab-delimited .txt file and using the Flat-File import.